# Integral over ellipsoid

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be the ellipsoid $\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=1\}$. Let $\omega=z  dx \wedge dy - y  dz \wedge dx$ and compute $\int_\Gamma \omega$. So I thought about parameterizing the ellispoid and doing spherical coordinates but they have different radii so I was wondering how Id go about this directly? Would my $x$ bounds be $0$ to $1$, my $y$ bounds be $0$ to $2$ and same for $z$? And for $z$ in the integral so I wolve for $z$ in the ellipsoids equation and same for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Have you considered using Stokes' theorem?

Comment: The map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,2y,3z)$ sends your ellipsoid to the usual sphere (or the other way atound, you need to check). Use a parametrisation of the sphere to deduce one of the ellipsoid thanks to that map. But @NinadMunshi has a better advice.

Comment: $$\omega = dx \wedge d(yz)$$. introducing $y=2y', z=3z'$ and going to spherical coordinates is a possible path for integrating $\omega$ over the unit sphere.

Comment: @NinadMunshi but for Stokes' Theorem, isnt it $\int_M d \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega$ where in this situation $\Gamma$ isnt the boundary of any manifold, oh wait is it the boundary of the filled in ellipsoid?

Comment: is my $d \omega = 0$??

Comment: @anonymous yes to both

Comment: @NinadMunshi so its zero? by Stokes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Since there are still questions unanswered in
the comment section:

The two-form you are asked to inegrate is
$$
\omega=z\,dx \wedge dy - y\,dz \wedge dx\,.
$$
You should be able to see that your $d\omega$ is zero. If not ask a specific question about this calculation. Since this $\omega$ is defined in all of $\mathbb R^3$ the [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) is more than applicable and tell us that $\omega$ is not only closed but also exact.
The one-form $\eta$ such that $d\eta=\omega$ is obviously

> $$\eta=-zy\,dx$$

We do not even have to know it explicitly.
Since $\Gamma$ is a closed surface its manifold boundary is the empty set and Stokes
$$
\int_\Gamma\omega=\int_\Gamma\,d\eta=\int_{\partial \Gamma}\eta
=\int_{\emptyset}\eta
$$ tells us what?

Comment: Yes, i got $d \omega = 0$, I see it now. Could you check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822494/closed-but-not-exact-form-on-bbbrn-setminus-0) out?

Comment: And as the form is exact, the integral along any compact submanifold is zero, correct? There is a theorem in Lee that states if for all compact submanifolds, the integral of a form is non zero, then the form is not exact. So exact $\Rightarrow$ integral along compact submanifolds is zero.

Comment: I am watching your other question already. Once Ted is in the loop you should work hard and you will learn a lot. Now to your question:  "And as the form is exact, the integral along any compact submanifold is zero, correct?" Please rephrase this properly. You only have to read my answer word for word.

Comment: and how would you rephrase that comment? The text literally says "Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, and suppose $S \subset M$ is a compact oriented smooth manifold without boundary and $\omega$ is a closed $k-$form on $M$. If $\int_S \omega \neq 0$, then $\omega$ is not exact."

Comment: It is worth the effort. I began to learn in recent years here on MSE that this is the core of a lot of very interesting math that has analogies even in algebraic topology/geometry.

Comment: Oh I left out $\omega$ $\textbf{closed}$.. Also, I see differential forms appear in algebraic geometry a lot.

Comment: The *key word* in that text is ***without boundary***. That boundary is our empty set $\partial\Gamma$ in this example.