# closed but not exact form on $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be the $(n-1)-$form on $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ defined by

$$\omega = \vert \vert x \vert \vert^{-n} \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}x^j \, dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge \, \hat{dx^j} \wedge ... \wedge \, dx^n.$$

Where $\hat{}$ denotes omitting the component. Prove $\omega$ is closed but not exact. So for closed I would just need to show $d \omega = 0$, right? And how would I even GO about finding the exterior derivative of $\omega$? And for not being exact, do I suppose

$$\omega = d \eta$$

for some $(n-2)-$form $\eta$ and deduce a contradiction? Thanks for any tips or hints. Been staring at this one for quite some time.

**Attempt**

To show $\omega$ is not exact, suppose there exists a differential form $\eta$ such that

$$\omega = d \eta.$$

Then by Stokes' Theorem, on one hand one has

$$\int_{S^{n-1}} d \eta = \int_{\partial S^{n-1}} \eta = \int_{\emptyset} \eta = 0.$$
I fail to see why

$$\int_{S^{n-1}} \omega \neq 0.$$

I found a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286162/closed-not-exact-form-on-mathbbrn-setminus-0?rq=1) but dont really understand it. Also, I fail to see why $d \omega = 0$. I am having trouble computing the exterior derivative of this sum with the norm on the outside. Also, the solution posted currently doesnt have the $(-1)^{j-1}$ term.

Comment: Have you tried the case when $n=2$?

Comment: What is the integral of an exact form over the unit sphere?

Comment: @TedShifrin isnt it zero? Because if the integral over a compact submanifold is nonzero then the form is not exact. Correct?

Comment: The statement you made follows from mine, not the other way around. What’s the proof of mine?

Comment: @TedShifrin by stokes’ theorem the boundary of sphere is empty set thus the integral should be zero but it’s nonzero. I.e., one side is nonzero one side is zero as the boundary of sphere is empty.

Comment: Right. So if you integrate this form over the sphere, why is the answer nonzero?

Comment: @TedShifrin thats what I am failing to see tbh. Anyone reading this could you elighten me on this plz!

Comment: And so the contradiction is that on one hand the integral yields zero and on one hand yields $2\pi$? @DamianRössler

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake (note that I deleted my comment). My comment only applies to $n=2$ (if you restrict the differential form to ${\bf R}^2$ when $n>2$, it will vanish for degree reasons). My guess is that you can compute the integral for any $n$ in the same way, using a trigonometric parametrisation of the sphere.

Comment: @anonymous:  The integral is the $n-1$-dimensional area of the sphere.  There are formulas on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) along with some explanation how to do the area and volume integrals inductively on the dimension.

Comment: You do *not* want to evaluate by parametrizing. That’s fine when $n=2$, but gruesome in higher dimensions. Note that when $\|x\|=1$, the form is equal to something simpler and smooth everywhere, so that then you *can* apply Stokes’s Theorem to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part I:**
Let's show $d\omega = 0$. Rewrite:
$$\omega = \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\bigg(\frac{x^j}{||x||^n}\bigg) dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge \hat{dx^j} \wedge ... \wedge dx^n.$$

---

Then since $d_k:\Omega^{k}(M)\to \Omega^{k+1}(M)$ is linear, we get:
$$d\omega = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}d\bigg[\bigg(\frac{x^j}{||x||^n}\bigg)  dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge \hat{dx^j} \wedge ... \wedge dx^n\bigg]$$
$$:= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}d\bigg(\frac{x^j}{||x||^n}\bigg)\wedge \big[dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge \hat{dx^j} \wedge ... \wedge dx^n\big] \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star)$$

---

The 2-norm, $||x|| := \sqrt{(x^1)^2+...+(x^n)^2}$, which implies $\partial_i||x|| = \large \frac{x^i}{||x||}$.
As well, $df:= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\partial_ifdx^i$ together with the product rule, power rule, and chain rule gives:
$$d\bigg(\frac{x^j}{||x||^n}\bigg) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\bigg[\frac{\delta^j_i}{||x||^n} +x^j\cdot\bigg(\frac{-n}{||x||^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{x^i}{||x||}\bigg)\bigg]dx^i$$
$$=\bigg[\frac{||x||^2-n(x^j)^2}{||x||^{n+2}}\bigg]dx^j+\sum\limits_{i\neq j}^n\bigg[\frac{-nx^ix^j}{||x||^{n+2}}\bigg]dx^i \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star\star)$$

---

Noting that $dx^i\wedge dx^i = 0$ for any $i$, substituting $(\star\star)$ into $(\star)$ results in:
$$d\omega = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\bigg[\frac{||x||^2-n(x^j)^2}{||x||^{n+2}}\bigg]dx^j\wedge \big[dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge\hat{dx^j} \wedge ... \wedge dx^n\big]$$
$$= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\bigg[\frac{||x||^2-n(x^j)^2}{||x||^{n+2}}\bigg]dx^1\wedge ... \wedge dx^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{||x||^{n+2}}\bigg[n||x||^2-n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(x^j)^2\bigg]dx^1\wedge ... \wedge dx^n = 0.$$
This shows $\omega$ is closed, as desired. $\square$

---

---

**Part II:**
We want to show $\omega$ is not exact. Applying Stokes' Theorem over the *filled hypercube* (instead of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$) gives the contradiction. We don't need the empty boundary, we just need nonzero integral.
Suppose $\omega$ is exact, then $\exists \eta \in \Omega^{n-2}\big(\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}\big)$ such that $d\eta = \omega$. Naively:
$$0 = \int_Cd(d\eta) = \int_Cd\omega = \int_{\partial C}\omega.$$

---

Define the face parameterizations in our punctured space as:
$$F_{\pm x^i}:(-1,1)^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$$
$$(s^1,...,s^{n-1})\mapsto (s^1,...,\underbrace{\pm 1}_{i^{th}\text{-coord}},...,s^{n-1}).$$
Then since $d(x^i\circ F_{\pm x^i}) = 0$, the only surviving term in the pullbacks are the ones with $j=i$. So:
$$\color{darkblue}{F^*_{\pm x^i}(\omega) = (-1)^{i-1}\bigg(\frac{\pm 1}{(||s||^2+1)^{n/2}}\bigg)ds^1\wedge ... \wedge \widehat{0} \wedge ...\wedge ds^{n-1}}.$$

---

Lastly, we have:
$$\int_{\partial C}\omega = \sum\limits_{\pm x^i}\int_{(-1,1)^{n-1}} F^*_{\pm x^i}(\omega) = 2*\sum\limits_{+x^i}\int_{(-1,1)^{n-1}} F^*_{+x^i}(\omega)$$
because the negative faces reverse orientation (choose outward normal on $\partial C$ and standard on the domain, then look at the differential at a point). Looking at the dark blue expression, we see that the RHS is nonzero, giving us the contradiction. So $\omega$ is not exact. $[\text{ }]$

Comment: I'm actually not 100 on the very last summation being nonzero. The $(-1)^{i-1}$ could combine the terms in some unforeseen way to be zero, it is worth trying to carry on with however, since it is right there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with a general problem, it can help to look at a simple special case. Here, you may look at $n=2$.

Then, your one-form is (do you see this?)
$$\omega =\frac{1}{\left|x\right|^2}\left(x^1 \mathrm{d} x^2 - x^2 \mathrm{d}x^1\right)\,.$$
The exterior derivative is
$$ \mathrm{d}\omega = \partial_1 \left(\frac{x^1}{\left|x\right|^2}\right)\mathrm{d} x^1\wedge \mathrm{d} x^2-\partial_2 \left(\frac{x^2}{\left|x\right|^2}\right)\mathrm{d} x^2\wedge \mathrm{d} x^1\,.$$
Do you see that  this vanishes?

For the integral, you can choose the unit circle (parameterised by $x^1=\cos t$, $x^2=\sin t$). Can you write $\int_{S^1}\omega$ as an integral $\int \mathrm{d} t$ of something and see that it does not vanish?

Comment: shouldnt it be $x^1 dx^2 - x^2dx^1$?

Comment: @anonymous of course, fixed

Comment: isnt the integral just $2\pi$? Its just $\cos^2 t dt + \sin^2 t dt = dt$ and its from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: Well, there's your answer!

Comment: nice, thanks! I think i get it now!!